# Custom UINavigationBar iOS with UITextView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to accomplish the following on iOS:
Custom UINavigationBar iOS with two UITextView

Bellow you can see the same on Android.

Is this possible with UINavigationBar ?
How can I do this ?

I tried using a UIBarButtonItem with a custom UIView but it seems that is limited on the size so couldn't accomplish what I want.

[image: Android Example]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. It won't be possible with storyboards and probably wouldn't even try.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()


    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.yellow


    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)

    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let textViewOne = UITextView()
    textViewOne.text = "1000"


    window?.addSubview(textViewOne)
    //top constraint

    window?.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(100)]-16-|", views: textViewOne)

    window?.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-16-[v0(24)]", views: textViewOne)
    return true
}



extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll just need to add the rest of the objects